# UPDATE que no hace caso a todas las condiciones del WHERE con POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy realizando un update en el que uso 3 tablas. Esta es:

```
UPDATE tt_common
SET tr_exclude = TRUE 
FROM tt_common c LEFT JOIN tr_transactiontr trans ON cast(SUBSTRING(trans.txid, 3, 7) AS INT) = c.id
INNER JOIN tt_rentavariable r ON r.ttcommon_ptr_id = c.id
WHERE trans.id IS NULL AND c.tr_exclude IS FALSE AND c.fecha_operacion >= '2018-11-13' AND c.fecha_operacion < '2018-11-15';
```

En el where hace caso a todo menos el rango de fecha.
También he probado así aunque es lo mismo:

```
AND c.fecha_operacion BETWEEN '2018-11-01 00:00:01' AND '2018-11-15 24:00:00'
```

Con el mismo resultado. ¿Cómo debería hacerlo para que me haga caso a todos los casos del WHERE?

Muchas gracias anticipadamente

Comment: Buenas, ¿que tipo de dato es fecha_operacion? ¿timespan?

Comment: es TIMESTAMPTZ, pero es super raro porque si haces una consulta si que funciona buscar la fecha asi

Comment: Si es raro, ¿Has probado de coger toda la parte de abajo a partir del from y meterle en una select? haber si arroja lo que quieres

Comment: Si lo he probado y realiza la query con el rango de fechas correcto

Comment: Además si quito las 2 tablas y solo dejo un, es decir así:
UPDATE tt_common SET tr_exclude = FALSE WHERE fecha_operacion >= '2022-01-01' AND fecha_operacion < '2023-01-01'; 

esto lo hace bien

Comment: Agrégale paréntesis AND (c.fecha_operacion >= '2018-11-13' AND c.fecha_operacion < '2018-11-15'); e intenta nuevamente.

Comment: tampoco funciona

Comment: Reemplaza el `UPDATE tt_common SET tr_exclude = TRUE` por un `select tt.*`, las filas que te devuelva van a ser las que se actualicen cuando uses el `update`  Un `where` funciona exactamente igual en el `select` que en el `update`. Me parece que el problema viene por otro lado, que significa ¿Qué "no hace caso"? ¿El update no funciona? ¿Te da un error o algún mensaje? ¿Funciona parcialmente? ¿Cuáles son las filas que no actualiza? ¿La tabla tiene algún trigger que eventualmente impida la actualización?

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo había hecho una subconsulta y efectivamente funciona

UPDATE tt_common c
SET tr_exclude = TRUE
WHERE c.id IN (
 SELECT c.id
 FROM tt_common AS c
 LEFT JOIN tr_transactiontr AS trans ON cast(SUBSTRING(trans.txid, 3, 7) AS INT) = c.id
 INNER JOIN tt_rentavariable r ON r.ttcommon_ptr_id = c.id
 WHERE c.fecha_operacion>='2018-11-13'AND c.fecha_operacion<'2018-11-15' AND trans.id IS NULL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE tt_common c
SET tr_exclude = TRUE
WHERE c.id IN (
    SELECT c.id
    FROM tt_common AS c
    LEFT JOIN tr_transactiontr AS trans ON cast(SUBSTRING(trans.txid, 3, 7) AS INT) = c.id
    INNER JOIN tt_rentavariable r ON r.ttcommon_ptr_id = c.id
    WHERE c.fecha_operacion>='2018-07-13'AND c.fecha_operacion<'2018-07-15' AND trans.id IS NULL);
```

Realizando una subconsulta funciona

Muchas gracias por la ayuda